# How to open a another page in website on click on anchor with a slide effect instead page load directly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I m trying to open a new page in my website by clicking on a anchor link but instead of directly loading the whole page, i want it to slide the new page from the side, like we often see in mobile applications.

I did tried searching for the related code in stack and others as well. But so far what i got is this....

```
<a id="add" href="https://www.google.com" class="show_hide">Click</a>

<script type="javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link tag
            $(this).slideToggle(1000);
        });
 });
 </script>
```

The above code, i tried lead me no where and opened the page as usually, i want the content to slide from side as it loads like in android apps.

Any help is appreciated guys. Sorry if my explanation or my question sounds a bit vague.

Comment: You cannot do this when making a redirect to a new page. The current DOM will be unloaded and the new one drawn in its place. To make this work you need to completely change your page architecture to an SPA (Single Page Application) which is not a trivial task. Then you will be able to load content via AJAX and animate it in to the page however you desire

Answer (score 1):

You can open the website in an IFRAME, and slide the IFRAME from the side.

For e.g.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" />
<script>
myiframe.src='http://www.thewebsite'
myiframe.css({position:'absolute',top:0,left:800})
myiframe.animate({left:0})
</script>
```